# How to scroll to element using Nightwatch?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I am using nightwatch for e2etesting my app. One of the tests fails because it cannot scroll to the element that it is testing I suspect. Question do I need to scroll or is there another way to do it? This is the element I am testing:

```
 return this.waitForElementVisible('#myElement', 4000) //wait for it to be visible
       .assert.visible('#myElement')
       .click('#myElement')
```

The element is at the top of the page but the testrunner has scrolled a bit down the page and it is not visible in the screenshot.
How can I if need be scroll to this element? or : How can I test this element?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is a native method in nightwatch to get elements into view. (In general elements should always be scrolled into view from nightwatch/selenium. But if you want to do that by hand you can use [getLocationInView()](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#getLocationInView):

```
return this.getLocationInView('#myElement')
   .assert.visible('#myElement')
   .click('#myElement')
```

Nightwatch also supports doing this directly via the Webdriver Protocol using [moveTo()](http://nightwatchjs.org/api/moveTo.html) without any abstraction. In that case it would look more like:

```
const self = this;
return this.api.element('#myElement', (res) => {
  self.api.moveTo(res.value.ELEMENT, 0, 0, () => {
    self.assert.visible('#myElement');
    self.click('#myElement');
  })
});
```

(this was just written from top of my head, hope I didn't make a mistake)

But what could help in your case is changing seleniums element scroll behaviour in the config like:

```
firefox: {
  desiredCapabilities: {
    browserName: 'firefox',
    javascriptEnabled: true,
    acceptSslCerts: true,
    elementScrollBehavior: 1
  }
}
```

Default is 0 -> Elements are scrolled to top of page

elementScrollBavior 1 -> Elements are scrolled to bottom of page

Comment: It would be helpful to mention that the native method is http://nightwatchjs.org/api/moveTo.html

Comment: @MikeDavlantes Thanks for you input. I tried to extend my description, hope I remembered how to use it in nightwatch correctly :'D

Answer (score 8):

Remember that:

> `.execute()` inject a snippet of JavaScript into the page for
>   execution in the context of the currently selected frame. The executed
>   script is assumed to be synchronous and the result of evaluating the
>   script is returned to the client.

and

> `Window.scrollTo()` Scrolls to a particular set of coordinates in the
>   document.

Your test will look like this:

```
module.exports = {
    'your-test': function (browser) {
        browser
            .url("http://example.com")
            .waitForElementPresent('body', 2000, "Be sure that the page is loaded")
            .execute('scrollTo(x, y)')
            .yourFirstAssertionHere()
            .yourSecondAssertionHere()
            ...
            .yourLastAssertionHere()
            .end()
    }
};
```

- If you know that the element with id `myElement` is at the top of the page you can just change `x` and `y` by `0` (just to be sure that you'll scroll to the top of the page).
- If you need to get the exact values of `x` and `y`, you can use: `getLocationInView()` like this:

  `module.exports = {
      'your-test': function (browser) {
          browser
              .url("http://example.com")
              .waitForElementPresent('body', 2000, "Be sure that the page is loaded")
              .getLocationInView("#myElement", function(result) {
                  //The x value will be: result.value.x
                  //The y value will be: result.value.y
              });
      }
  }`

  > .getLocationInView(): Determine an element's location on the screen
  >   once it has been scrolled into view...
  >   Returns The X and Y coordinates
  >   for the element on the page.

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 8):

you can use the [moveToElement()](http://nightwatchjs.org/api#moveToElement)

simply use it like this

```
browser.
.moveToElement(#myElement, 10, 10)
.waitForElementVisible(#myElement, 500)
```

Comment: If the element is below the fold, will it "scroll" the screen to move that elements into the viewable area?

Comment: moveToElement doesn't work in Firefox.  It's a known issue.

Answer (score 3):

You can execute this javascript with `execute` `document.querySelector({{ACTUAL_SELECTOR}}).scrollIntoView();`

Comment: `scrollIntoView()` is compatible in all major browsers. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView#Browser_compatibility

Answer (score 1):

In addition an example I used as page object command (be_expand) where my selector was an xpath already used in a element (@be_click):

```
    be_expand() {
        this.api.execute(function(xpath) {
            function getElementByXpath(path) {
                return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;
            }
            var res = getElementByXpath(xpath);
            res.scrollIntoView(true);
        }, [this.elements.be_click.selector]);
        this.assert.visible('@be_click');
        this.click('@be_click');
        return this;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.execute('scrollTo(0,3000)');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
browser.execute('window.scrollTo(0, 1080)')
```

This one work for me to scroll to the bottom of the page.