# How to bring an element to the browser's viewpoint with Nightwatchjs

Tags: javascript, selenium-chromedriver, nightwatch.js

I am trying the scroll down and bring an element to the browser's viewpoint. Which is at the bottom of the page and not visible unless scroll down.

With the help of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43059368/how-to-scroll-to-element-using-nightwatch) Stackoverflow post I am able to get the `x and y` for the element but not able to bring it to the viewpoint.

```
    browser.getLocationInView('#element', function (result){
        console.log ('x: '+ result.value.x);
        console.log ('y: '+ result.value.y);
    })
```

> This gives me x: 16, y: 519

After that I tried

```js
browser.execute('scrollTo(16, 519)')
```

This does not scroll it to the viewpoint. What is the way to do this?

Well, perhaps I did not understood the use of these apis in right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are Nightwatch APIs that work fine if you have to scroll an element into the viewport.

`moveToElement` is my first choice always as it takes element selector as param and brings the element to top of the viewport.

`moveTo` is a great choice if you have to use the element's location. The docs are available [here](https://nightwatchjs.org/api/moveToElement.html#apimethod-page).

Below is the syntax.

```
.moveToElement(selector, xoffset, yoffset, [callback])
.moveToElement(using, selector, xoffset, yoffset, [callback])

.moveTo([webElementId], xoffset, yoffset, [callback])
.moveTo(null, xoffset, yoffset, [callback])
```